# Pitch accent of 問題なだけなのだ

Tags: pitch-accent

Apparently, the correct pitch accent of 問題なだけなのだ is: もんだいな{HHHHH} ・ だけなのだ{LHLLL} (two accent phrases)

I don't understand why だけ creates a new accent phrase here (I don't think it usually does) and why there is a drop after だけ. I would like to learn the more general rules that explain the pitch behavior of なだけなのだ in this phrase.